# Hide Traffic Manager Endpoint from Search Engines but Expose the Custom Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, search-engine, robots.txt, azure-traffic-manager

I'm running a ASP.NET MVC website hosted on Azure and using Traffic Manager as load balancer, thus the users can not only visit the website by custom domain like **foobar.yourcompany.com**, but also endpoint provided by Azure Traffic Manager like **foobar.trafficmanager.net**. So do Search Engine crawlers.

Is there any feasible solution to hide the Traffic Manager endpoint from crawlers and expose the custom domain endpoint?

P.S. I know *robots.txt*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup your app to return an HTTP 301 permanent redirect to your custom domain when accessed over the Traffic Manager domain, it should stop it from showing up in search results. As far as I know, you can't fully disable the TM domain. Similarly like you can't fully disable the App Service domains.

So e.g. if your app gets a request for:

```
http://foobar.trafficmanager.net/foo/bar
```

Redirect it with an HTTP 301 to:

```
http://foobar.yourcompany.com/foo/bar
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it can be done with IIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182087/iis-rewrite-rule-to-redirect-specific-domain-url-to-different-url-on-same-domain

Comment: But will the "foobar.trafficmanager.net" address still be rendered as web result on search engine result pages?

Comment: Yeah absolutely! IIS Rewrite can do the job. Do check its options carefully so it redirects correctly :)

Comment: It should not be shown. Google etc. should consider a 301 redirect as a sign that they should not index that, but index the thing it is pointing to. This is how many websites implement "canonical" URLs in that their site will reply on "www" and bare domains, but they redirect one to the other so search results are not duplicated.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks for your help!